# How to define the equal operator for hstore type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an HSTORE type like this to my model:

```
serialize :settings, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
```

I then added the following in my model to get a key value without having to use the square brackets.

```
# Add the possibility to inquire HSTORE keys values without brackets
#   ex. @company_settings.settings['locale'] => @company_settings.locale
def method_missing(id, *args, &block)
  if settings.has_key?(id.to_s)
    settings.fetch(id.to_s)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Is there any way to do the same for the equal operator? i.e.

> @company_setting.locale = 'en'

EDIT

This is the error I get if I do '@company_setting.locale

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `locale=' for #<CompanySettings:0x42e9a78>
from D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
from D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:126:in `method_missing'
from D:/ASM/source/app/app/models/company_settings.rb:23:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: Is the following `@company_setting.locale = 'en'` raising an error? Because in the method_missing it receives *args and &block, maybe you have to play with this to modify the setter method?

Comment: Not even the slightest idea of how to define a setter for a hash key

Comment: Maybe add an elsif condition? `elsif settings.has_key?("#{id.to_s}=")` and do your magic inside

Comment: Final answer is : elsif settings.has_key?(id.to_s[0..-2]) settings.store(id.to_s[0..-2], args[0])